Showing minimum of the set $A_n = \{ x : |x - a | < \frac 1n \text{ and } |f(x) - f(a)| \geq \epsilon \} $ does not exist
I was recreationally reading this in Goldrei's Classic Set Theory (page 113).

The margin, marked in red by me, claims it is easy to show $A_n$ has no minimum.
I gave it a shot out of curiosity but have not been successful at all! One strategy I tried was to take $x \in A_n$ and try to exhibit a $y \in A_n$ which is strictly less than $x$. But this works easily only in the case when $ x > a$, and not for the cases $x = a$ and $x < a$, where it leads to a dead-end since we cannot as easily guarantee existence of something to the left of $x$ in $B_{\frac 1n} (a)$.
This makes me suspect that perhaps this statement in the margin is not true; that there might in fact be cases where a minimum could exist. I however cannot find such an example!
But judging from how the text is phrased in the margin, it seems it should not depend on the function $f$, and namely always be true that the minimum of $A_n$ does not exist, regardless of how $f$ is constituted (beyond the hypotheses in the statement).
Am I misunderstanding something? Thanks!

@Steen82 What a weird comment

It can exist sometimes, for fixed choices of $f, n, a, \epsilon$. For instance, let $f(x) = \mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{Q}}$ but modify $f(1/2) = 100$. Then if $a=0, n=1, \epsilon = 2$, $A_n$ is a one-element set $A_n = \{1/2\}$ so it certainly has a minimum.
